# Screen tearing in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I develop the endless runner. I move objects with update

```
-(void) update:(CCTime)delta{
ast.position = ccpAdd(ast.position, ccpMult(ccp(-200,0), delta));
if(ast.position.x<-100)
   [ast setPosition:ccp(_winSize.width+100,ast.position.y)];
}
```

But i have one problem. Object, witch i want to move is twitching.
I tried set fps to 30 but it did't help. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't screen tearing, it's a side effect of multiplying with delta time. Short answer: don't multiply with delta time: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/10/game-engine-multiply-delta-time-or-not/